# Extend django rest framework to allow inheriting context in nested serializers

Tags: django, python-2.7, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django 1.6 (very soon upgrading to 1.8), Python 2.7, and DRF 3.2.5 (very soon upgrading to latest).

I've got a set of deeply nested serializers (~10 levels deep, with a total of 20-30 models that are serialized).
I'm trying to add a boolean flag to the context, which will determine whether the serialized output hierarchy will be detailed (include all models' fields) or basic (part of the fields only).

I wrote the following code (partial snippet):

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from app.models import Institute, Department, Member

class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super(MemberSerializer, self).get_fields()
        if self.context['basic_view']:
            for field in ['height', 'weight']:
                del fields[field]
        return fields

    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('id', 'birth_date', 'height', 'weight')


class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = MemberSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super(DepartmentSerializer, self).get_fields()
        if self.context['basic_view']:
            for field in ['type', 'manager']:
                del fields[field]
        return fields

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'type', 'manager', 'members')


class InstituteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    departments = DepartmentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super(InstituteSerializer, self).get_fields()
        if self.context['basic_view']:
            for field in ['name', 'type']:
                del fields[field]
        return fields

    class Meta:
        model = Institute
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'type', 'departments')

def get_entities(is_basic_view):
    institutes_list = Institute.objects.all()

    serializer = InstituteSerializer(institutes_list, many=True, read_only=True, context={'basic_view': is_basic_view})

    return serializer.data
```

But then found out that the 'context' that is passed from 'get_entities' to 'InstituteSerializer' is not passed-on to the nested serializers.
Meaning that in the example above - InstituteSerializer has 'basic_view' in the 'context', but MemberSerializer & DepartmentSerializer don't.

I found a working solution in [context in nested serializers django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560470/context-in-nested-serializers-django-rest-framework) : to use SerializerMethodField per nested field (e.g. 'departments'), and in the 'get_' method to manually pass-on the context.
My problem with that solution is that it requires embedding this code 20-30 times in my code, eventually doubling the number of source lines.

My request - if someone has (or can help implement) an extension for serializers.ModelSerializer, which will get an additional parameter upon construction, e.g. 'inherit_context'.
Then the only thing I'll need to change in my classes, for example in 'InstituteSerializer', is the addition of that parameter:

```
class InstituteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    departments = DepartmentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, inherit_context=True)

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super(InstituteSerializer, self).get_fields()
        if self.context['basic_view']:
            for field in ['name', 'type']:
                del fields[field]
        return fields

    class Meta:
        model = Institute
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'type', 'departments')
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand well, but why don't you simply pass on that context? E.g. calling `departments = DepartmentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, context=self.context)` from the `InstituteSerializer` with the context it previously received?

Comment: @C14L it's not possible since 'self' is an unresolved reference at this point

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently I missed something...
The 'context' **is already inherited** down to the nested serializers...

**However,** the reason it didn't work for me, is because as part of my nesting, some of the child serializers were defined via serializers.SerializerMethodField().
And in such as case **(only!)** the context is **not** automatically inherited.

The solution is to simply pass-on the 'context', within the 'get_...' method related to each SerializerMethodField:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    child = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_child(self, obj):
        child = ....
        serializer = ChildSerializer(instance=child, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data
```

P.S - a DRF github issue similar to mine was created a while ago: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2555