# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri' Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got this Serializer translating path to url, and it works on its own, but when i try to nest this serializer inside another serializer, i get this error. Do you have any idea why? I need to have this function, because otherwise it just shows the paths to the image in this main SpecialistSerializer.

```
class EntityPhotosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_file_abs_url')


    class Meta:
        model = EntityPhoto
        fields = ('user', 'entity', 'image',)

    def get_file_abs_url(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request.build_absolute_uri(obj.image.url)
```

```
class SpecialistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reviews_quantity = serializers.IntegerField(source="get_reviews_quantity")

    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['photos'] = EntityPhotosSerializer(many=True, instance=instance.entityphoto_set.all()).data
        return data
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 282, in get
    return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 56, in retrieve
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 548, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/Users/jakubstrawa/programming/PythonKuba/api/specialists/serializers.py", line 35, in to_representation
    data['photos'] = EntityPhotosSerializer(many=True, instance=instance.entityphoto_set.all()).data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 745, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 664, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1870, in to_representation
    return method(value)
  File "/Users/jakubstrawa/programming/PythonKuba/api/specialists/serializers.py", line 23, in get_file_abs_url
    return request.build_absolute_uri(obj.image.url)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [context in nested serializers django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560470/context-in-nested-serializers-django-rest-framework)

Comment: no :( still can't figure it out.

Comment: Added  child = serializers.ListField(read_only=True, child=EntityPhotosSerializer())
Still AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'

Comment: You need to pass the context to the `EntityPhotosSerializer` constructor. Also I'd recommend restructuring a bit to more closely match the linked answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `to_representation`, you access to the `EntityPhotosSerializer`. And in that serializer, you are trying to access to the context. If you want to do that, you need to pass the current context to `EntityPhotosSerializer` in `SpecialistSerializer`.

```py
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['photos'] = EntityPhotosSerializer(many=True, context=self.context, instance=instance.entityphoto_set.all()).data
        return data
```

Comment: Yes i just figured that adding context=self.context has helped. Thank you anyways:)