# How to pass request as an argument to serializer in serializer method field

Tags: django, image, django-rest-framework, request, django-serializer

I have a main serializer, and I also have a serializer for my **BOOK** model so I made a method to return a serialized queryset using my **BOOK SERIALIZER**

BUT the problem is ** I can't access my main serializer context through BookSerializer**

What can I do?

**Views.py:**

```
class BookMainPage(ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.select_related('owner').all()

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'user': self.request.user, 'book_id': self.kwargs.get('pk'), 'request': self.request}

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.kwargs.get('pk') is None:
            return MainPageSerializer
        return BookComplexSerializer
```

**MainPageSerializer:**

```
class MainPageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    @staticmethod
    def get_new_books(self):
        return BookSimpleSerializer(Book.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:10], many=True).data

    @staticmethod
    def get_popular_books(self):
        return BookSimpleSerializer(Book.objects.all().order_by('-bookRate')[:10], many=True).data

    @staticmethod
    def get_most_borrowed(self):
        return BookSimpleSerializer(Book.objects.all().order_by('-wanted_to_read')[:10], many=True).data

    new_books = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_new_books')
    popular_books = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_popular_books')
    most_borrowed_books = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_most_borrowed')
```

**BookSimpleSerializer:**

```
class BookSimpleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['id', 'picture']

    def get_picture(self, obj: Book):
        request = self.context['request']
        photo_url = obj.picture.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(photo_url)

    picture = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_picture')


class CategorySimpleSerializer(serializers.ModelSeria
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [context in nested serializers django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560470/context-in-nested-serializers-django-rest-framework)

Comment: No it didn't it raises an error that your BOOK model doesn't have context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can intiialiaze your serializer passing a context with your request in the MethodField method:

```
class MainPageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def get_new_books(self):
        return BookSimpleSerializer(
            Book.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:10], 
            many=True, 
            context={"request": self.context["request"]}
        ).data

    def get_popular_books(self):
        return BookSimpleSerializer(
            Book.objects.all().order_by('-bookRate')[:10], 
            many=True, 
            context={"request": self.context["request"]}
        ).data

    def get_most_borrowed(self):
        return BookSimpleSerializer(
            Book.objects.all().order_by('-wanted_to_read')[:10], 
            many=True, 
            context={"request": self.context["request"]}
        ).data

    new_books = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_new_books')
    popular_books = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_popular_books')
    most_borrowed_books = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_most_borrowed')
```

And i remove the staticmethod decorator. Your method does not have to be static